# Replace fields types in interfaces to promises

Tags: typescript, generics, asynchronous, interface, promise

Typescript has `Partial<Object>` type that helps to make the all fields of object optional.

Is it possible in the same way to create a generic type `Promisify<Person>` that will change the `Person` type from:

```
interface Person {
  getName(): string;
  getAge(): number;
}
```

to:

```
interface PromisifyPerson {
  getName(): Promise<string>;
  getAge(): Promise<number>;
}
```

I have an synchronous API described via Typescript interfaces and my goal is to create asynchronous version of API without rewriting the all interfaces what I have. This is another example:

```
interface ApplicationApi {
  startApp(): void;
  readFile(fileName): string; 
}

type AsyncApplicationAPI = Async<ApplicationApi>
```

after that I expect that AsyncApplicationAPI should be something like:

```
interface AsyncApplicationApi {
  startApp(): Promise<void>;
  readFile(fileName): Promise<string>; 
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to wrap local values in a Promise?  That adds extra overhead for no reason.

Comment: I have an API described via Typescript interfaces. This is API for desktop application and almost all methods are synchronous. Now I have to create a remote client for this API, and I want to reuse already existing interfaces. But remote client will call API in asynchronous way. So I think about to transform the sync API interface to async one with something like ` type AsyncApplicationAPI = Async<ApplicationAPI>`

Comment: I guess I'm confused why you wouldn't return all the values in the API call instead of each *property* (let me get the name of this person via ajax... now let me get the age of this same person via another ajax call).  If I need a person why not `Promise<Person>`?

Comment: I just added some more description. I already have a huge amount of API interfaces that is too hard to rewrite now. My goal is to create an asynchronous version of API without changes in original API.

Answer (score 1):

```
type Promisified<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? 
        (...args: Parameters<T[K]>) => Promise<R> :
        T;
}
```

Or see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMsgOYRgBycAthABQCUAXMhmFKGQNzGkUwAQQrM2IAK60ARtD5EAvsWJgAngAcUqKFlrAMwGMAgATADwAVAHzIAvPn6lkAbQDSyUMgDWEVVhjIFgC6bBZuQcgQAB6QICYYyAwAdClwUGQYbHAgqkx2NqAw0MgASsgA-I5OTsmp6ZloaXSUmJbhVnm2Ntq6+hBmJTYsVdWB8kpExAg4HMjq6FDYIGw9egZGpmYLSzb2kgA2+8hwCRIgXiBYAO64J8c58sTzmDhJgiKMTDzIAPQ-yABabo6Nb9SQyaBWHhAA).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could create it, though it may take some work. You could simply create a function that would iterate over every property of the given object, and return an object that is identical except for the data members being wrapped in Promises, and the functions wrapped in new functions that return promises. Of course, you would have to worry about specifics, like if you wanted all of the objects properties' properties to be wrapped in promises or not...

edit: my answer would make it so you could pass an *instance* of an object and get a promisified *instance* back. You might not be able to do it for types in general from within the language itself.

Comment: Yeah, it's not hard to create a function that will replace the all field in object to Promises. However my goal is to create a type based on another type.

Comment: Ah yes, ok. This is a very in-depth question. I'm guessing you would need to define it from outside the language, in the compiler. Maybe it's something to bring up more directly with the Typescript people on their Github page?

Comment: Unfortunately their github page says: this is not a forum - use "stackoverflow" for your questions

Comment: hmm...Interesting. Well, if no solution exists, it could go as a "feature request"